# How to edit view created programmatically

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-cardview

So in my application i have a linear layout, to which i'm adding programmatically some CardViews (android L cardview) like this :

```
    //This is my LinearLayout
    LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.accounts_layout);

    //Here i create my CardView from a prepared xml layout and inflate it to the LinearLayout
    View card = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.account_card, myLayout);

    //Now i change the 'text' value of the Card's text views
    TextView cardTitle = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.text_card_title);
    cardTitle.setText("Title1");
    TextView cardDecription = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.text_card_description);
    cardDecription.setText("Description1");
    //...

    //Now i do the same thing for another card
    View card2 = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.account_card, myLayout);

    TextView cardTitle2 = (TextView) card2.findViewById(R.id.text_card_title);
    cardTitle2.setText("Title2");
    TextView cardDecription2 = (TextView) card2.findViewById(R.id.text_card_description);
    cardDecription2.setText("Description2");
    //...
```

The two cards are displayed properly, but what happens is than the first card displayed has "Title2" and "Description2" written in the textViews, while the second card has the default values defined in the xml.
It seems to me that by calling `card.findViewById()` or `card2.findViewById()` i get always the TextView of the first card.
So my question is : how do i manage to differentiate the cards i create programmatically and then correclty access the view within them?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
        LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.accounts_layout);
        for (int i=1;i<=2;i++){

            View card = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.account_card, null);
            TextView cardTitle = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.text_card_title);
            cardTitle.setText("Title"+i);
            TextView cardDecription = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.text_card_description);
            cardDecription.setText("Description"+i);

            card.setTag(i);
            card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
                    Toast.makeText(context,pos,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            myLayout.addView(card);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks that way it worked! But another problem came up : i put some header properties to the card in my xml (height, width, border, ecc..) but now those properties aren't being considered anymore!